# Writing to csv file more than one user input?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a user input. The first is for user to put in their name. The following will be destinations.

The below code writes to line 1 in csv. Hover if the code runs again and user inputs a different name I want it to write to the next line. Line 2.

```
  class writeToCSVfile:
     def __init__(self):
        self.name = []

    def writeIt(self):
    import csv
    with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        data = [['Name', 'Home Airport','Destination' 'Stopovers','Cheapest Route'],
                [b.name,        xy,       b.input2,     b.input3  ],



a.writerows(data)

writ = writeToCSVfile()
writ.writeIt()
```

[What the CSV file looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfEr2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use append mode when openinig the file and should work:

```
with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
```

You must deal with the headers

```
['Name', 'Home Airport','Destination' 'Stopovers','Cheapest Route']
```

to not append them everytime to the file.